# How to make input box bigger as text area?

Tags: php, html

I have searching everywhere to find answer for this problem but didn't found, how to make input box wide and bigger as text area where we can set their cols and rows?

My code as below:

```
<td align="right">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row_remark['remark']; ?>" name="remark" rows="8" cols="30">
</td>
```

Comment: Just use textarea in your form instead.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you can't. Why? because that's what `<textarea>` is for.

Comment: Exactly. `<textarea>` is essentially a `<input type="text">` element with specified length and width (in number of characters, because they always have monospaced text, useful in your situation). If you wanted to make the text not monospace, use an editable `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `textarea` tag for that. Here is an example:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

You can use the `cols` and `rows` properties to give the box the size you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<textarea>` instead.  It's a bit counter-intuitive, but this is effectively an input type as well.  Not sure why textarea isn't a valid `<input type='textarea' ...>` but it's not; Rather, it's an explicit tag.

Answer (score -1):

with input type text you can't do that you can make it it bigger using css height and width but it can have just one line in it 
so if you want bigger space you have to use  chek bootstarp they have some nice css to go with textarea

Comment: using a input you can put it full width using style="width:100%" in a row